# MySQL Sort 2nd and 3rd Column based on the 1st Column

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like below:

```
--------------------------------------------
|col1    |col2            |col3            |
--------------------------------------------
|123.com |/path/to/234.com|/path/to/456.com|
|234.com |/path/to/123.com|                |
|456.com |                |/path/to/789.com|
|789.com |                |                |
--------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to sort both colume2 and colume3 based the data on colume1?

The final table should looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|col1    |col2            |col3            |
--------------------------------------------
|123.com |/path/to/123.com|                |
|234.com |/path/to/234.com|                |
|456.com |                |/path/to/456.com| 
|789.com |                |/path/to/789.com|
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The records in the output do not match the result set in the input.  You should add starting sample data to your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Is there a correspondence between col1 and col2?
According to your target results, the contrast between col1 and col2 has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a sorting issue. You'd need to self join the table to rearange the rows.

For the given example you could use something alog the lines of:

```
SELECT t1.col1,
       t2.col2,
       t3.col3
       FROM elbat t1
            LEFT JOIN elbat t2
                      ON t2.col2 LIKE concat('%', t1.col1)
            LEFT JOIN elbat t3
                      ON t2.col3 LIKE concat('%', t1.col1);
```

But it seems more like you have a serious design issue there if the data in a row doesn't belong together.

Comment: Thanks mate. Bear with me I'm not a programmer. May I ask what is t1, t2, and t3? I know it's a mess, so I'm trying to sort it.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I also took this as reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp   That was really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I got another question. How can I keep the order of the first table? t1.col1 in this example, if I made a left join, the order of the col1 will be changed.

Comment: @NeilWang: Tables represent relations, a special type of sets and sets have no order, so there's no order to retain. You can use `ORDER BY` if you have a column that defines the order.